# Monotouch read XAML

Tags: xamarin.ios

Hi can I read a XAML file using MonoTouch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as XAML is a text format (XML), of course you can *read* it.

What do you want to do with it?

If you want to use WPF, then no, it isn't supported yet on mono.

Comment: the System.XAML namespace to b able to read XAML easily into objects.

Comment: @Lennie - To deserialize XAML, since it is XML, you can use [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) or [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx). The [`XamlServices`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Xaml/System.Xaml/XamlServices.cs) class has been implemented in mono, so you can use [this approach](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bursteg/archive/2009/05/18/xaml-in-net-4-0-serialization-and-deserialization-using-xamlservices.aspx).